# Directly accessing a union within a struct

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following tagged union:

```
typedef struct Form {
    FormType type;
    union {
        TaxForm tax; 
        BusinessForm bus; 
    } u;
} Form;
```

To access the main/sub object I have to do:

form->u.bus

Is there a way to either do:

```
form->u
```

Or:

```
form->bus
```

That is, to be able to access union object directly without going through its  declarator (since by definition, the union will only have one item set).

Comment: @M.M oh, I didn't even know you could do that...Want to post an answer saying just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this by omitting the `u` from the original definition:

```
typedef struct Form {
    FormType type;
    union {
        TaxForm tax; 
        BusinessForm bus; 
    };  // <--- no u
} Form;
```

Then you can use `form->bus` and so on, where `form` is a pointer to `Form` .

This is called "anonymous unions" and was added in the C11 standard revision , so you will need to invoke your compiler in C11 or later mode, or hope that it supported this as an extension in older modes.